# Largest message size for XChaCha20-Poly1305

Tags: authenticated-encryption, chacha, poly1305

[libsodium documentation](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/secret-key_cryptography/aead/chacha20-poly1305/xchacha20-poly1305_construction) says that XChaCha20-Poly1305 can encrypt a message of arbitrary size.

However, the [only specification available](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-arciszewski-xchacha-03) (still a draft) explains that under the hood the IETF version of ChaCha20-Poly1305 is used (in combination with HChaCha20 for key derivation), which implies at the very least a hard limit of 256GB because of the 32 bit counter.

Who is right, and how large can a message be at most to be safely encrypted with XChaCha20-Poly1305?

And what about the authenticated data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should email the libsodium maintainers and the internet-draft author and ask them to talk to each other to work out what they mean, and to clearly document the limits in the internet-draft.  (They sometimes post here but not often.)

In principle, XChaCha provides $2^{256}$ 512-bit blocks of output under a single key, indexed by a 256-bit input.  The only question is how they are carved up for messages *vs.* blocks within a message.

- For the [XSalsa20 stream cipher](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#xsalsa), the message number is 192 bits, and the block number is the remaining 64 bits, so the theoretical limit on the number of blocks per message is $2^{64}$, or $2^{70}$ bytes.
- For the Salsa20 stream cipher [as in eSTREAM](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#salsafamily) and [as in NaCl](https://nacl.cr.yp.to/valid.html), and for the related ChaCha stream cipher, the message number is 64 bits and the block number is the remaining 64 bits, so again the limit on blocks per message is $2^{64}$.
- For the IETF ChaCha stream cipher of [RFC 7539](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7539), the message number is 96 bits and the block number is 32 bits, so messages are limited to 256 GB.
- The current XChaCha-Poly1305 internet-draft, [draft-arciszewski-xchacha-03](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-arciszewski-xchacha-03), is defined in terms of the IETF ChaCha-Poly1305 AEAD of [RFC 7539](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7539) as a subroutine, in [§2, p. 3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-arciszewski-xchacha-03#page-3), but it follows the XSalsa20 API, so the message number—which is a parameter to the API—is 192 bits, but the block number—which is managed internally by the API—is 32 bits; the remaining 32 bits of the internal ChaCha input are fixed to zero.
- In what libsodium seems to implement for `crypto_aead_xchacha20poly1305_ietf`, according to the [XChaCha20-Poly1305 construction page](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/secret-key_cryptography/aead/chacha20-poly1305/xchacha20-poly1305_construction) ([archived 2019-05-30](https://web.archive.org/web/20190530101720/https://download.libsodium.org/doc/secret-key_cryptography/aead/chacha20-poly1305/xchacha20-poly1305_construction)) and the [AEAD limitations table](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/secret-key_cryptography/aead) ([archived 2018-11-07](https://web.archive.org/web/20181107120831/https://download.libsodium.org/doc/secret-key_cryptography/aead)), the message number is 192 bits and the block number is 64 bits, like XSalsa20.

  - *If the byte order of the block number is chosen appropriately*, this should be *compatible* with draft-arciszewski-xchacha-03 in the sense that it can correctly implement any protocol following the internet-draft, but it also allows much larger messages that are not allowed by the internet-draft.
  - It is also possible that the block number encoding is mismatched so that libsodium's `crypto_aead_xchacha20poly1305_ietf` is incompatible with draft-arciszewski-xchacha-03—I haven't checked.

All that said, the distinction between a 32-bit block number and a 64-bit block number is essentially academic: the largest message any implementation is willing to *receive* is the largest amount of memory that an adversary waste in a denial of service before you can drop the message on the floor.  It is hard to imagine applications for which this amount should reasonably be beyond a few megabytes, let alone 256 GB—larger messages can simply be broken up into smaller pieces at negligible additional cost since the per-piece overhead is at most a few dozen bytes, even if you include the 192-bit nonce and some formatting metadata.

Comment: I think you're significantly underestimating the size of messages some users may want to send and receive, especially if "send" actually means e.g. "write to a backup disk" and "receive" means "restore the backup".

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Not at all.  They should be broken up into smaller pieces.

Comment: Arguably so, yes, but only because commonly used encryption modes tend to have low message size limits. There is no other reason why the use case I describe should need a chunked encryption scheme, and implementing one securely is nontrivial. (Of course, in practice most file encryption software seems to use homegrown schemes based on e.g. CBC+HMAC, if they do message authentication at all. But it would be nice if they *could* use standard AEAD modes instead.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen No, it's bad idea to do things in bulk like that because you can't drop forgeries on the floor sooner, so you're setting yourself up for denial of service of the receiver.  For backups you probably also want deduplication and replication by erasure coding, for which you'll want to break things into chunks anyway.  Breaking a sequential stream like this into chunks is not hard: _e.g._, use the chunk sequence number as the nonce, and never reuse a key for different streams (or incorporate a stream number into the nonce).

Comment: Denial of service is not (much of) an issue if you don't accept unsolicited messages to begin with. For the backup file encryption example, sure, a corrupted backup file can result in the restorer wasting some minutes or hours decrypting it only to be told that it's invalid. But at that point *the major issue is that the backup has somehow been corrupted*, not that the corruption was only detected at the end of the decryption process, rather than, say, only 10% of the way through it (which cannot be guaranteed, anyway).

Comment: ... And your "not hard" solution fails to detect the removal of chunks from the end of the stream. Of course, that's easy enough to fix once you realize it's an issue, but not everybody will. Like I said, it's not trivial.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen If we're talking about a disk backup, presumably there is an authenticated manifest specifying among other things how large it is.  If we're talking about an online conversation, presumably there is a way to terminate the conversation like a FIN.  If your application has neither a manifest with length, nor explicit stream terminator, _and_ you need it in the cryptography for some reason, then, well, all it takes is a single additional bit in the nonce to indicate end-of-stream or not, and you have exactly Rogaway's rather simple STREAM construction.

Answer (score 3):

All the responses above are correct.

Libsodium (and Libhydrogen 0.x, that introduced this construction) uses a 64 bit block counter, effectively allowing an arbitrary large message to be encrypted under a given (key, nonce).

Arciszewski's draft restricts that counter to 32 bit, because this is easier to implement on top of an existing ChaCha20-IETF implementation (vs the original ChaCha20 design).

The former is compatible with the latter.

Comment: How can they be compatible to each other if they don't behave in the same way for plaintexts larger than 256GB?

Comment: As written above, the former is compatible with the latter. The reverse is not true. That being said, the draft is... a draft, and is still subject to changes. If supporting a 64 bit counter happens to be something applications may actually need, this can be suggested on the draft's github repository: https://github.com/bikeshedders/xchacha-rfc

Answer (score 2):

XChaCha20-Poly1305 is NOT the same as IETF ChaCha20-Poly1305. IETF ChaCha20 uses a 96-bit nonce and 32-bit counter, XChaCha20 uses a 192-bit nonce and 64-bit counter. The 64-bit counter lets it encrypt an absolutely staggering amount of data (1 Zettabyte) in a message. For all practical purposes there's no limit, since no one is going to be sending the entirety of the data of all the worlds computers in one message.

Therefore Libsodium's documentation is correct about XChaCha20. The IETF's documentation is correct about the IETF ChaCha20, but that's not what you're asking.

Poly1305 does not restrict the maximum size of the message being authenticated.

Comment: Where is the 64 bit counter defined? The [draft spec of XChaCha20-Poly1305](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-arciszewski-xchacha-03) in section 2.3 defines XChaCha20 as HChaCha20 (KDF) + IETF ChaCha20, and the latter has a 32 bit counter.

Comment: libsodium's documentation is correct according to what?  Correct documentation of its own implementation?  What is your authority for the claim that ‘XChaCha20 uses a 192-bit nonce and a 64-bit counter’?  Please cite sources.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage It is correct according to [section 2.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-arciszewski-xchacha-03#section-2.1) of the draft spec already linked, the [XSalsa paper](https://cr.yp.to/snuffle/xsalsa-20110204.pdf), and the underlying mathematics of the overall construction. The limit of 64-bits on the counter is due to the `block counter` in the Salsa20 algorithm; ChaCha20 can be substituted for Salsa20 which means all of the basic rules carry over.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 §2.1 of the internet-draft is about the _nonce_, not about the _block counter_.  The proposed XChaCha is _not_ a direct analogue of XSalsa20 because it is limited to $2^{32}$ blocks per message, not $2^{64}$ blocks per message as XSalsa20 is.  This is because it is defined in terms of IETF ChaCha which is limited to $2^{32}$ blocks per message (rather than djb ChaCha which allows up to $2^{64}$ blocks per message), as you can see in [§2.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-arciszewski-xchacha-03#section-2.3).

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Let me try to clarify: I mentioned 2.3 of the draft because it explicitly states that up to 2^80 messages can be sent with a 192-bit nonce. The counter was brought up because it is a feature of the Salsa and ChaCha algorithms and is ultimately what caps us at either 2^32 or 2^64 (the latter is possible if using the extended versions). Quoting the spec "XChaCha20 **can** be constructed from an existing ChaCha20 implementation and HChaCha20." Therefore, all sources agree about the limitations (though the fact that we're here means it things could be made clearer.

Comment: An AeadChaChaPoly1305 implementation that directly [depends on `XChaCha20`](https://dev.azure.com/byteterrace/CSharp/_git/ByteTerrace.Maths.Cryptography.AeadChaChaPoly1305?path=%2FProject%2FAeadXChaCha20Poly1305.cs) is also slightly simpler because it is constructed in the exact same way as one that [depends on `ChaCha20`](https://dev.azure.com/byteterrace/CSharp/_git/ByteTerrace.Maths.Cryptography.AeadChaChaPoly1305?path=%2FProject%2FAeadChaCha20Poly1305.cs).

Comment: @Kittoes0124 If you implement ‘XChaCha’ in terms of IETF ChaCha, then it is limited to $2^{32}$-block messages.  If you implement ‘XChaCha’ in terms of djb ChaCha, then it is limited to $2^{64}$-block messages.  The internet-draft is _explicitly defined_ the first way in §2.3, and is therefore limited to $2^{32}$-block messages, so that when it becomes an IETF standard it will be compatible with the IETF standard ChaCha; but the implementation of libsodium is defined the second way, presumably because there's no technical reason to restrict it to $2^{32}$-block messages.

Comment: My point is that this answer does not address the internet-draft, and claims ‘libsodium's documentation is correct about XChaCha20’ without citing the authority for ‘correctness’.  There are two obvious options for that authority—libsodium's implementation, which is a kind of vacuous authority; and the IETF internet-draft, relative to which this statement is false, because the internet-draft's XChaCha is limited to $2^{32}$-block messages.  So at best this post is misleading, and at worst this post simply fails to answer the question.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Sorry if this is too blunt but that's where you're wrong. Everything stated in the answer is 100% accurate: XChaCha20-Poly1305 is *not* the same as ChaCha20-Poly1305, Libsodium's implementation *is* correct according to the procedure laid out in [the XSalsa paper](http://cr.yp.to/snuffle/xsalsa-20110204.pdf), the IETF draft is right about it being possible to construct XChaCha20 by using the HChaCha and ChaCha20 constructions, and Poly1305 does not restrict message size. The authority here should be DJB and his papers, not some draft document created by a random engineer.

Comment: Finally, if one reads [the draft](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-arciszewski-xchacha-03#section-2.3) carefully, it says that we **can** construct XChaCha20-Poly1305; not that we have to.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 The internet-draft is a _specification_ that defines ‘XChaCha’, which, if finished, would become IETF XChaCha, which can be correctly implemented using IETF ChaCha as a subroutine.  There is no djb XChaCha; the libsodium XChaCha _cannot_ be correctly implemented using IETF ChaCha as a subroutine.  I'm not saying either the internet-draft XChaCha or libsodium XChaCha is right or wrong; I'm saying it's wrong to claim ‘libsodium's documentation is correct’ without saying what authority the correctness is relative to (and wrong to say unqualified ‘XChaCha20 uses a 64-bit counter’).

Comment: (Obviously, you could implement libsodium XChaCha vacuously ‘using IETF ChaCha as a subroutine’ by reimplementing ChaCha from scratch and ignoring the subroutine, or by carefully varying the nonce every 256 GB with multiple separate calls to IETF ChaCha, but libsodium XChaCha can't be defined in terms of a single call to IETF ChaCha for messages ${>}2^{32}$ blocks the way internet-draft XChaCha can be.)

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Why do you keep blatantly ignoring the single authority that defines what ChaCha and XChaCha are? The algorithm laid out in XSalsa can be trivially lifted and applied to base ChaCha (which, let's not forget, actually does have a 64-bit counter; in an attempt to make nonce reuse less likely implementations typically reduce this counter to 32-bits and expand the nonce from 64-bits to 96-bits). The "real" algorithms have some flexibility and, while the IETF drafts arguably contain "best practices", let's not pretend that they are **the** authority; that's always gonna be djb.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 I'm not interested in having a measuring contest about whose authority is biggest—although I would be curious to hear if you can cite the publication by djb that is the ‘single authority that defines…XChaCha’—but I do care about clearly communicating _which_ authority is being used in a claim of ‘correctness’.  IETF ChaCha is a real thing, and it is probably even more widely used than djb ChaCha, since it is used in TLS 1.3.  The question was about _both_ libsodium _and_ the internet-draft; either one could serve as an authority and the answers for each are different.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I apologize since that wasn't my intention; I'm merely passionate about the implementation details (as defined by the inventor of the algorithms [ChaCha](https://cr.yp.to/sigs/rwsota-20080131.pdf), [Poly1305](https://cr.yp.to/mac/poly1305-20050329.pdf), and [XSalsa](https://cr.yp.to/snuffle/xsalsa-20110204.pdf)). The XSalsa paper is the only possible authority to reference for XChaCha since it explicitly lays out the construction for the underlying hash function; which is simply reused in HChaCha. Nothing against IETF draft, it makes good use of djb's clever maths.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 It's true the XSalsa20 paper has the only _reasonable_ construction for key derivation used by anything one might call ‘XChaCha’, as libsodium and the internet-draft do. But ${>}2^{32}$-block messages aren't really reasonable, and IETF ChaCha is widely used. (By the way, if yer gonna be a stickler about djb nomenclature, consider keeping the 20's straight: ChaCha is to Salsa20 as ChaCha20 is to Salsa20/20; in ChaCha<r> or Salsa20/<r>, <r> is the number of rounds, while plain ChaCha and Salsa20 are the stream cipher families. ChaCha8 and Salsa20/12 also see some use in the world.)